# Error with Xstream

Tags: xml, list, arraylist, compiler-errors, xstream

I'm having the following error:

```
Security framework of XStream not initialized, XStream is probably vulnerable.
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field GameList.Game
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No such field GameList.Game
field               : Game
class               : GameList
required-type       : GameList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /GameList/Game
line number         : 2
version             : not available
-------------------------------
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.handleUnknownField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:524)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:375)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:281)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:70)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1486)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1466)
        at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1337)
        at Start.main(Start.java:11)
```

I'm trying to get the Game object inside the GameList of the GameList.xml file, however, it always returns that error.

Start.java (main code):

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{

        XStream xstream = new XStream();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("Games.xml");
        GameList gamelist = new GameList();
        gamelist.setGames((ArrayList<Game>) xstream.fromXML(reader));

        xstream.alias("Game", Game.class);
        xstream.alias("Games", GameList.class);
        xstream.addImplicitCollection(GameList.class, "Games", Game.class);


    }
}
```

GameList.java code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GameList {

    private ArrayList<Game> Games = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setGames(ArrayList<Game> Games2){

        Games.clear();
        Games2 = Games;
    }

}
```

Game.java code:

```
public class Game {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String plataforma;

}
```

I have already managed to make Xstream read simple xml codes that are not list type, however, I need to make it read codes with lists now.

Answer (score 0):

The alias is being set after you are trying to read the XML and hence `XStream` is not able to understand how to deal with the XML containing the list elements.

The alias for the list should be set before reading the XML. Please modify the code as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException {

    XStream xstream = new XStream();
    xstream.alias("Game", Game.class);
    xstream.alias("Games", GameList.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(GameList.class, "Games", Game.class);

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("Games.xml");
    GameList gamelist = new GameList();
    gamelist.setGames((ArrayList<Game>) xstream.fromXML(reader));
}
```